# Connect two joomla websites user base

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I have 2 Joomla websites, and I want to achieve the following functionality:

Whenever somebody registers on Website#1, I want the same user to be created automatically on Website#2.

I know, I could do this by sharing the users table, but this would only be a one way thing, so that is not a good option.

Are there any extensions, that would export / migrate users automatically upon a trigger (registration), or I should create a plugin / extension myself, or a PHP script?

Comment: Probably better to ask this on the dedicated Joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se].